# Preint one specific array element, when I click stop button

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval, clearinterval

I am repeatedly looping through an array, my aim is to stop the loop and printout a specific element in the array and display it through span id="fruit". please see code below :

```js
var title = ['233249864597', '233209425159', '233201112221', '233546056136', '233266549303', '233209409846', '233501345825', '233248446422', '233546112136', '233541006033', '233502089334', '233552476293', '233268222280', '233202240898'];

var i = 0; // the index of the current item to show
var animate = setInterval(function() {
  // setInterval makes it run repeatedly
  document
    .getElementById('fruit')
    .innerHTML = title[i++];
  // get the item and increment
  if (i == title.length) i = 0;
  // reset to first element if you've reached the end
}, 15);

function stop() {
  clearInterval(animate);
}
```

```html
<h1>THE WINNER IS : </h1>
<h1><span id="fruit"></span></h1>

<center><button onclick="stop()">STOP</button></center>
```

Comment: Your problem is unclear, what behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Can you describe more? What is your expected output ?

Comment: If you want the numbers to not appear until you click STOP, then don't change the `innerHTML` inside the `animate` function, and instead only update the `innerHTML` inside the `stop` function

Comment: my code printouts all elements in an array ,it scrolls through the arrays,like a raffle system, when i click on stop button i want the the code to stop on printout just one specific item in the array as the winner.

Comment: i want the numbers to appear, just that i only want the scrolling to stop on a specific number in the array ,anytime i click on stop

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
const title = ['233249864597', '233209425159', '233201112221', '233546056136', '233266549303', '233209409846', '233501345825', '233248446422', '233546112136', '233541006033', '233502089334', '233552476293', '233268222280', '233202240898'];

const winner = title[3]; // for example

var i = 0; // the index of the current item to show
var animate = setInterval(function() {
  // setInterval makes it run repeatedly
  document
    .getElementById('fruit')
    .innerHTML = title[i++];
  // get the item and increment
  if (i == title.length) i = 0;
  // reset to first element if you've reached the end
}, 15);

function stop() {
  clearInterval(animate);
  document
    .getElementById('fruit')
    .innerHTML = winner;
}
```

```html
<h1>THE WINNER IS : </h1>
<h1><span id="fruit"></span></h1>

<center><button onclick="stop()">STOP</button></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var title = ['233249864597', '233209425159', '233201112221', '233546056136', '233266549303', '233209409846', '233501345825', '233248446422', '233546112136', '233541006033', '233502089334', '233552476293', '233268222280', '233202240898'];

var i = 0; // the index of the current item to show
var animate = setInterval(function() {
  // setInterval makes it run repeatedly
  //document.getElementById('fruit').innerHTML = title[i++];
  // get the item and increment
  if (i == title.length) i = 0;
  // reset to first element if you've reached the end
}, 15);

function stop() {
  clearInterval(animate);
  document.getElementById('fruit').innerHTML = title[i++];
}
```

```html
<h1>THE WINNER IS : </h1>
<h1><span id="fruit"></span></h1>

<center><button onclick="stop()">STOP</button></center>
```

Comment: That is not a specific number and will give an error when i === title.length-1

Comment: ? " ... to stop on a specific number in the array ,anytime i click on stop"

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

I changed the numbers to fruits because.. well... I just wanted to write out some fruits.
But they can be changed back to numbers ofc.

```js
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pineapple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Watermelon'];

var i = 0; // the index of the current item to show
var animate = setInterval(function() {
  i++
  document
    .getElementById('fruit')
    // use modulus operator to stay inside array
    .innerHTML = fruits[i % fruits.length];
}, 15);

function stop() {
  clearInterval(animate);
}
```

```html
<h1>THE WINNER IS : </h1>
<h1><span id="fruit"></span></h1>

<center><button onclick="stop()">STOP</button></center>
```